# It feasible to use MVP to differentiate the presenter for a control used in 2 contexts

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, mvp

I have a WinForms UserControl which I am using in 2 different applications.  A Word Add In and another  WinForms application.  I would like to be able to differ the implementation of say a check in operation based on which application I am in, as there are unique concerns in both applications.

I am struggling however with what to do with the UI concerns which are specific to each application.  For example, I want to check the active documents in the Word Add in, but obviously dont want to do this in the WinForms app.   I have resolved the fact that I can inject the presenter but I am aware I should keep UI logic out of there.  Do I need another layer or do I need to write 2 different versions of the control, which share alot similarities.

Comment: It appears you need to compose your view based upon the host application. Wouldn't you benefit from encapsulating the platform discoverability logic in presenter and use the logic in view render/initialization to use the correct control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better to abstract out common functions in a separate project and create 2 different implementation for that abstraction.